# Encountered compile time error when embedding sql statement in sub-procedure

Tags: rpgle

I've done embedded sql in sub-procedures before.  But this one just won't cooperate. 
 It is giving me compile time error.  Below is a stripped down version of the code.  If I change this myProc sub-procedure into a sub-routine, it compiled fine.  But I need it to be in a sub-procedure.

```
P myProc          B                                      
D                 pi                                     

   // calling stored procedure to get result set        
   exec sql call lrGetLoginResetEmailsSP(:sqlTotRow_RE); 

   // associate the RS and open cursor                   
   exec sql associate result set locator (:sqlRS_RE)     
            with procedure lrGetLoginResetEmailsSP;      
   exec sql allocate C1 cursor for result set :sqlRS_RE; 

   // fetch and close                                     
   exec sql fetch C1 into :sqlRcd_RE;                    
   exec sql close C1;                                    

P                 E
```

Below is the compile errors that I'm getting

```
*RNF7030 30        096100  The name or indicator SQL_00000 is not defined.
*RNF7030 30        096100  The name or indicator SQL_00003 is not defined.
. . .
```

When I look at the compile listing, I noticed that the compiler did auto generated those SQL_00** variables.  But they are being generated into a totally unrelated sub-procedure.  It should have generated them in the main D spec.  Here is the compile source:

```
033100 P clrOtherPrfsSF...                                                                             
033200 P                 B                                                                             
033300 D                 pi                                                                            
033400                                                                                                 
033500   //clear the subfile                                                                           
096100 D                 DS                  STATIC                               CALL                 
096100 D  SQL_00000              1      2B 0 INZ(128)                             length of header     
096100 D  SQL_00001              3      4B 0 INZ(4)                               statement number     
096100 D  SQL_00002              5      8U 0 INZ(0)                               invocation mark      
096100 D  SQL_00003              9      9A   INZ('0') CCSID(*JOBRUNMIX)           data is okay         
096100 D  SQL_00004             10    128A   CCSID(*JOBRUNMIX)                    end of header        
096100 D  SQL_00005            129    132I 0                                      SQLTOTROW_RE
```

Weird...

Comment: hmmmm... if I move the myProc sub-procedure to be the very first procedure in the program source file, it compiled successfully.

Comment: do you have an sql statements in main part of program?  If not, just a guess, try putting one there like a exec sql set option ......  Maybe that will put the SQL_* definitions at the global level.  This could be version related too.

Comment: I do.  I've this: exec sql set option datfmt=*iso, commit=*none;

Answer (score 2):

There's a PTF for that: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas3SI68275

Here's how I found it: I went to the RPG Cafe's new main page (https://ibm.biz/rpg_cafe) and put "crtsqlrpgi rnf7030" into the general "Support" search bar at the top.

These were the top 3 hits. I picked the second one, and it was the 7.3 PTF.

> ```
> Resolving CRTSQLRPGI that fails with RNF7030,RNF7503 using RPGPPOPT(*LVL2)
> SI68275 - SQL-CMPL-MSGRNF7030 CRTSQLRPGI FAILS WITH RNF7030 AS SQL PRE
> SI68274 - SQL-CMPL-MSGRNF7030 CRTSQLRPGI FAILS WITH RNF7030 AS SQL PRE
> ```

When I changed the search to add "v7r3m0", the SI68275 PTF came up first, and the APAR was second.

> ```
> SI68275 - SQL-CMPL-MSGRNF7030 CRTSQLRPGI FAILS WITH RNF7030 AS SQL PRE
> SE69905 - SQL-CMPL-MSGRNF7030 CRTSQLRPGI FAILS WITH RNF7030 AS SQL PRECOMPILER INSERTS RPG STATEMENTS INCORRECTLY
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`exec SQL set option ....` is actually a compile time statement, not run-time, and must be the very first SQL statement encountered in the source.

In a *SRVPGM module, I'll often have the following as the very first procedure in the module...

```
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
   //  SetSqlOptions
   //
   // The SQL SET OPTION statement is a compile time statement
   //   It must be physically the first SQL statement the compiler sees
   //   during compilation.  the options are in effect for the entire module
   //
   //   Thus this dummy procedure that isn't ever called.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
   dcl-proc SetSqlOptions;

      exec sql set option  naming =*sys, commit= *none, usrprf= *owner,
            dynusrprf= *owner,datfmt= *iso, timfmt = *iso,
            closqlcsr= *endactgrp, alwblk = *allread,
            alwcpydta = *optimize, dlyprp = *yes;
      return;
   end-proc;
```

So in a cycle main *PGM, make sure `SET OPTION` is at the very beginning of the C-specs.

In a linear main, you could make the above procedure the very first one in the source.

Other than that, what version and PTF level are you running?

Comment: yes, the SET OPTION is at the very beginning of the C-Specs.  Yes, if I put the procedure that contains the sql statement to be the first procedure in the source, it compiled successfully.  We are on V7R3 CUMULATIVE PTF PACKAGE C8242730.

Comment: You don't even need to put the `SET OPTION` in a procedure. I always put it at the end of the global data declarations, along with any other compile time statements that do not need local variable definitions.